# How do I get nodemon to watch dotenv-flow files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon, dotenv

dotenv-flow files can have names like: .env, .env.development, .env.development.local, ...

see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-flow

I would like my node server to restart as soon as I update one of those files. However, adding a custom config, I am able to restart on a change in the .env file only.

```
"nodemonConfig": {
    "watch": [".env"]
}
```

How could I watch files **prefixed** with .env ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When overriding nodemon's `watch` list you need to provide a full match list. For example, to watch `js` files in the `app` directory, `.env`, and files prefixed with `.env` e.g. `.env.development`, you can use the following:

**nodemon.json**

```
{
  "watch": ["app/*.js", ".env", ".env.*"]
}
```

The same concept works for dotenv-flow

**dotenv-flow**

```
"nodemonConfig": {
  "watch": ["app/*.js", ".env", ".env.*"]
}
```

You'll likely need to modify the `watch` list a bit more to suit your needs. All in all, that's the gist.